# Executing a batch script on Windows shutdown

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, shutdown, group-policy

Is there any way, in `Windows 7 Professional`, to run a batch script (e.g., a .BAT file) when the user clicks on "shutdown" (not a batch file scheduled to shut down the machine, just one that runs only if the user clicks on "shutdown")?

Ideally, such a script would show the command prompt window and offer an option to cancel the shutdown procedure.

Solutions that do not require a third-party utility would be preferable.

Comment: Did you manage to prevent the shutdown? If yes, how did you do it? Thanks

Comment: If you want to prevent users from shutting down the computer, you can disable access to it in the start menu through Group Policy. Go to _User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar_ and look for **Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands**. This will hide those options from the start menu. If you need to allow them to restart, you can add a batch file to the _All Users\Desktop_ folder to call the command `shutdown.exe \r \t 10` which will force a restart of the computer after 10 seconds.

Comment: OK, how do you debug the scripts then?
Even just dumping the output to a file would help.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52581235/45375 asks how to _script_ (automate) the installation of a shutdown script (without the added requirement of presenting a visible console window to the user).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can create a local computer policy on Windows. See the TechNet at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789197(v=ws.11)

1. Run `gpedit.msc` to open the Group Policy Editor,
2. Navigate to **Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)**.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to prevent the shutdown from within a script attached to tbis Shutdown event?
I have tried a batch file with shutdown /a but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: thanks. Note you will need `Win Professional` or `Ultimate` to do this. If you have standard home version (like I did), then you can manually add the group policy editor from [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/).

Comment: Very helpful in scripting a `savestate` for a VirtualBox VM before shutdown. Thanks!

Comment: How would I be able to do this on "sleep" instead of "shutdown" ?

Comment: Note that, as mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows), if you want a batch script to run at Logoff, I found referencing the .bat file directly didn't work. However, if I used `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as the Script Name and `/C C:\path\to\batch\script.bat` as the Script Parameters, it did

Answer (score 5):

Well, its an easy way of doing some registry changes:
I tried this on **2008 r2** and **2016** servers.

Things need to be done:

1. Create a text file "**regedit.txt**"
2. Paste the following code in it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown] 

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown]     

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0]  
"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"    
"SOM-ID"="Local"    
"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"    
"DisplayName"="Local Group Policy"    
"GPOName"="Local Group Policy"    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0]    
"Script"="terminate_script.bat"    
"Parameters"=""    
"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00    

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown\0]
"GPO-ID"="LocalGPO"    
"SOM-ID"="Local"    
"FileSysPath"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine"    
"DisplayName"="Local Group Policy"    
"GPOName"="Local Group Policy"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts\Shutdown\0\0]    
"Script"="terminate_script.bat"    
"Parameters"=""
"IsPowershell"=dword:00000000
"ExecTime"=hex(b):00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

3. Save this file as **regedit.reg** extension
4. Run it on any command line using below command:

   ```
   regedit.exe /s regedit.reg
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Create your own shutdown script - called Myshutdown.bat - and do whatever you were going to do in your script and then at the end of it call shutdown /a.  Then execute your bat file instead of the normal shutdown.

(See http://www.w7forums.com/threads/run-batch-file-on-shutdown.11860/ for more info.)

Answer (score 3):

I found this topic while searching for run script for startup and shutdown Windows 10. Those answers above didn't work. For me on Windows 10 it worked when I put scripts to task scheduler. How to do this: press Windows key and write Task scheduler, open it, then on the right is Add task... button. Here you can add the scripts.
PS: I found the actions for startup and logout user, there is none for shutdown.

Comment: I can not find the `logout user` option when doing this. Is it called something else or how do I find it?

Answer (score 2):

For the above code to function; you need to make sure the following directories exist (mine didn't). Just add the following to a bat and run it:

```
mkdir C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
mkdir C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown
mkdir C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Startup
mkdir C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Shutdown
```

It's just that GP needs those directories to exist for:

```
Group Policy\Local Computer Policy\Windows Settings\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)
```

to function properly.

Answer (score 2):

Programatically this can be achieved with [SCHTASKS](https://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html):

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONEVENT /mo "Event[System[(EventID=1074)]]" /EC Security /tn on_shutdown_normal /tr "c:\some.bat" 

SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONEVENT /mo "Event[System[(EventID=6006)]]" /EC Security /tn on_shutdown_6006 /tr "c:\some.bat" 

SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONEVENT /mo "Event[System[(EventID=6008)]]" /EC Security /tn on_shutdown_6008 /tr "c:\some.bat"
```