# Is there any way to run service before shutdown the system?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service, startup, shutdown

I did a program to sign in and sign out of an application. I created a service (Windows batch file) and added the batch file in to windows start up programs. So my program starting automatically when I start my system (i.e. sign in to application). This is working fine. Now I wanted to know is there any way to run my service (Windows batch file) before shutdown my system ?

Comment: a BAT file in the startup folder is not a Windows service, so it does not get notified of shutdown events.

Comment: okay, Is there any way to run bat file on shutdown event

Comment: yes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown

Comment: Will try and let you know