# AWS EC2 run powershell script when scaling in

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, octopus-deploy

Is it possible to run a powershell script when scaling in servers before the instance is terminated? If so are there any examples of how to achieve this?

Scenario: I am planning on AutoScaling servers based on CPU.  I am automatically provisioning them into an Octopus Deploy environment (Continuous Deployment) but before they are terminated I need to unregister the instance with Octopus via a HTTP Post.

Comment: Not sure I follow. You can execute scripts in octopus either using script console, or you can create a process which executes custom powershell scripts. WHat would you need?

Comment: My specific case is Octopus Deploy specific but really I just need to be able to run *a* script when scaling in.  AWS Lifecycle hooks documentation seems fairly thin on the ground in terms of Windows.

Comment: I have the same issue and just end up running an hourly job that checks the Octopus environment for EC2 instances that are no longer available and deletes them from Octopus.  That way you do not depend on that powershell script running on your machine's death.

Comment: I believe Octopus Deploy 3.1 might alleviate your need for a job to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to tap into the shutdown event of windows but that might be unreliable depending on how rudely windows shuts off.

This might be useful [Executing a batch script on Windows shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown)

I would suggest using CloudWatch Alarms and using AWS SNS to subscribe to the events when the AutoScaling Group decreases in size and that message should have details of the machine that has just been removed.