# How to run user scripts at termination of windows ec2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I want to send an email at termination of a ***windows instance*** with some ***userdata*** using **SNS**.
is there any chance to run some scripts to send **SNS** message once i give the command for termination?
In ***Linux***, I read some where there is some option to put the script. Similarly is there a way to do the same in ***Windows instances***.
I tried **CloudTrail** feature, but I can't get ***userdata*** as it was not displayed.
Is there any other good option?

Comment: Are you asking:
1. How to get the userdata on a windows machine? OR
2. How to send SNS from a windows machine? OR
3. How to run a script when a windows instance is terminated?

Comment: option 3. How to run a script when a windows instance is getting terminated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows, depending on windows version you can set a policy to run a script during shutdown. The following link describes how to run a script when Windows 7 Professional is shutdown.

[Windows shutdown script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434863/executing-a-batch-script-on-windows-shutdown)

You have to fetch the userdata and send a SNS in that script.