# How to detect a shutdown and run code before shutdown execution in MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, events, shutdown

I have a web server cluster (windows 2008) that collects usage data from clients. The servers all batch the data and send after a certain time or amount of data. The problem is we are using AWS auto-scaling, and the machine can be shut down at any time. I would like to detect a shutdown event and send the usage data to the database before the application is killed. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, you can perform these tasks (in code/ yourself) when your server goes back up.

Otherwise look here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/bd8ea190-9bf4-4915-8ed9-96ee5d6f336a/when-are-windows-server-20032008-shutdown-scripts-run-in-the-shutdown-process

Comment: The server does not go back up, when they are shutdown they are terminated. I've trying to shut the site down in a batch file as you suggest, but I'm running into timing issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733989/halt-batch-file-until-website-stop-is-complete

Comment: Check also this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to this event and perform your logic before the application is shutdown.

**Application.Current.Exit +=DoSomething;**

Comment: Tried that. It works if the website is stopped manually, but not on a Windows shutdown. May need to modify the Windows shutdown policy so that it stops the site during a shutdown, as suggested by T.S.'s link.

Answer (score 0):

[WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) is NuGet package designed to clean up application `Start` and `Shutdown` registrations.

This will register your `MyStaticClass.Start()` and `MyStaticClass.Shutdown()` methods:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyStaticClass), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(MyStaticClass), "Shutdown")]
```