# Halt batch file until website stop is complete?

Tags: windows, batch-file, web

This question is very similar to [Halt batch file until service stop is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874911/halt-batch-file-until-service-stop-is-complete) but I would like to stop a website instead. I currently have `appcmd stop sites "siteName"` in the script, but the batch file just issues the stop command and continues. I would like for the batch file to wait until the site is stopped before continuing. I'm running Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to get this to work using a batch file. Something like this *might* work (but this probably won't work for you and doesn't work for some people):

```
:LoopWhileNotStopped

for /f "delims=" %x in ('appcmd list site "siteName"') do set siteInfo="%x"

IF NOT %siteInfo:~-16% == "state:Stopped)"
    GOTO :LoopWhileNotStopped
```

But I couldn't figure out how to modify the `set siteInfo="%x"` command so that it would work for the output of the *appcmd* command. The problem seemed to be that the *appcmd* output included double quotes and that interfered with command interpretation when the variable expansion is performed.

Here's a PowerShell script that should work:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe stop site "siteName"

do { Start-Sleep -s 1; $siteInfo = C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site "siteName" } until ($siteInfo -match "state:Stopped")
```

Comment: I got `x" was unexpected at this time.` running your loop code.

Comment: @AliEXE Yeah – that's what I meant by "Something like this *might* work", i.e. 'this probably doesn't work'. Did you try the PS script too? I'm not using IIS currently so I can't easily test this.

Answer (score -1):

Does `appcmd` return immediately no matter what?
This might work, depending on how appcmd behaves.

```
start /wait "site stop" appcmd stop sites "siteName"
```

If `appcmd` is a script, you could probably fix it so that it doesn't return immediately.

What web server are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously you are using IIS 7 or newer if you are using APPCMD.

1. I think you mean SITE rather than SITES.
2. You might have another file name APPCMD in your path.  Type APPCMD /? to see if you are
   executing what you think.
3. Try this to be sure you are executing the desired APPCMD:

   "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" stop site "siteName"