# How to run the bat file when the system is shoutdown

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file login.bat that contains

```
 java -jar D:/ERPLogin/Login.jar
```

The above code runs when the system starts it automatically running the my application.
Similarly when user click the shutdown button from **windows** before run my application then system shutdown immediately with out user interface

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to schedule a task to run when shutting down windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to register your application as a service to receive Windows pre-shutdown notification. However, I donæt know if this is doable from Java (You will need to use The Tanuki service wrapper for java, I could not find in their documentation about this, the closes I got was: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/integrate.html), so you will need to create a new application in C or C# (I am not aware that any other programming language under windows provides this service, but please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.)

The following links http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/106742/Creating-a-simple-Windows-Service and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164252.aspx explains this more or less the theory but uses Win32 API (the MSDN) which might be difficult for some to comprehend without necessary background.

http://www.sivachandran.in/2012/03/handling-pre-shutdown-notification-in-c.html gives an example in C#.

I recommend to go with the C# solution.