# Install application to run at Windows shutdown using Wix

Tags: windows, wix, shutdown

I know it its possible to [manually set scripts to be run at Windows shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows).
But using Wix, is it possible to install an application to be run at every Windows shutdown?

Please don't make premature value judgements about this. I need this because I need to collect some data from a serial port in a client machine, but an application keep the port busy, and I can't kill that application during business hours. But on shutdown process at the end of the day would be okay to kill it and collect data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what programs would need to be installed before every shutdown, but wouldn't just using the Windows Task Scheduler be an easier option?

Comment: I will need to install this program to be run at shutdown in a number of clients. The best case scenario would be to schedule this at installation. Is it possible to programatically set an application to be run at shutdown with Windows Task Scheduler? Using Wix?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=windows%20task%20scheduler%20run%20task%20at%20shutdown

Just read google. Tons of articles on tasks at shutdown

Comment: Came here from google.  Was told to go to google.  I will report back when I find a real answer since this is the top result