# Running Dropbox as a windows service automatically as soon as windows starts

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services

Actually, I want to run Dropbox as a windows service. Following this article, http://thedigitalhippies.com/forums/topic/4-running-dropbox-as-a-service-windows-server-2008-x64/ it works perfectly as i wish to.

Now, I want to start/run the dropbox service automatically as soon as the windows starts.

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler).

You just create a new task running Dropbox triggered when the computer starts:

- Create a [task when computer starts](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson2/all/) :  run the instance of dropbox with trigger "when computer starts"
- Kill a task using [taskkill command](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/224903-how-close-exit-some-program-using-task-scheduler-windows-7-a.html). You can either trigger it from the task scheduler or you can add it to the shutdown policy in [gpedit.msc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows)

Comment: Thank you but still not working as i wish. In my case, when i stop the dropbox service and turn off the computer and when i turn on computer, the dropbox service should start automatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use Task Scheduler if Dropbox has already been setup as a windows service. Just:

1. run the [services control panel application](http://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/essential-tools-windows-services-msc/) ("services.msc")
2. find the service you created to run Dropbox
3. Ensure that the service is set to start ["Automatic" -- or "Automatic (Delayed Start)"](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/services-control-panel-startup-type.jpg)