# Trigger python script on a system Shutdown

Tags: python, windows

I made a script that uploads all the files in a predefined folder to the cloud. Now what I want is I want this script to run everytime the user tries to shut down  the PC (running on windows 7) . So is there any way to achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/use-group-policy-editor-to-run-scripts-when-shutting-do-980849001

Comment: @Denziloe That helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `gpedit.msc` (local Policies).

And then, enter: `Windows settings` -> `Scripts` -> `Shutdown` -> `Properties` -> `Add`

In this file, you can write:
`python <path_to_the_python_file>`

Comment: I presume it's only .BAT files you can add?

Comment: You can call your python file from the BAT file... like:
```python <your's python file path>```

Comment: If I was helpfull, please approve the answer pls. @Denziloe

Comment: But I'm not @Zaid Khan ;)

Comment: Allright. In any case, I founded this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows, maybe you find it helpful.

Comment: I am trying to approve the answer but it says 'you can accept an answer in 8 minutes'