# How to Run a Python Script On Shutdown of System(Windows 7)

Tags: python, windows, shutdown

I want to run a python script before shutdown of system.I am using Windows 7.I have run python script on startup of system but i am not getting to run script before shutdown.

I Refer [How to schedule a task to run when shutting down windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows) and Many Questions like this on SO but somehow that's not working.Please anyone can tell me ?

Comment: Are you adding .py scripts or .bat? This will help you:[Creating a BAT file for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script)

Comment: .py scripts......

Comment: does startup and shutdown only works  for .bat file ? @avix

Comment: to make sure that your script executes when you shutdown your system, create a smiple __.bat__ file that contains something like `python your_script.py` so it runs your __.py__ script, then do whatever you have to do with the .bat file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does startup and shutdown only works for .bat file?

Yes, in windows as a startup/shutdown script you need to provide [Batch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file).

Here is workaround I would suggest for you.

1. Create .bat script with following code(assuming that you have python included in PATH):

   `for %%i in (/Shutdown/*.py) do python C:/Shutdown/%%i`
2. Add .bat script to windows shutdown schedule.

> Run *gpedit.msc*
>
> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts
>   -> Shutdown -> Properties -> Add

3. Create directory C:/Shutdown (if you want to use different directory - change path in .bat script).
4. Put all your .py scripts into C:/Shutdown. They will be now executed while windows shutdown.

Comment: An executable can be set as the 'script'. Just browse to add the fully-qualified path of "python.exe", and pass the fully-qualified path of the script as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me. I hade to write the following in the `.bat` file

```
for %%i in (/Shutdown/*.py) do @python.exe C:/Shutdown/%%i
```

I put the `.bat` file in the shutdown folder and addded this to the PATH. But I guess it doesn't matter if the .bat file is in another folder which is also included in the PATH ofcourse.

In the `gpedit.msc` I had to add the link to the `.bat` file in the User **Configuration -> Windows settings -> Script** field, not in the Computer Configuration.

I'm running Windows 10, and Python 3.7

Comment: or more simply `python c:/Users/vicente/Documents/startup.py`

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work in Windows 11 but it works if I moved the batch file to:

**User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts (Logon/Logoff) -> Logoff**