# Execute powershell before Azure VM shutdown

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm

Right before shutting down the VM, I would like to shut down certain windows services(in the same VM) our application using(graceful shut down). Is there an event in Azure VM that I can hook a powershell script to, so that it executes before shutting down the VM?

The current solution is to keep a schedule for Services shut down and then another schedule to shut down VM(every day). But when we need to deploy in between, then this approach fails.

Comment: I have a solution for this is you intend to use Automation Account for shutting down the VM.

Comment: If you meant schedule then it is already done. The question is more about hooking up the shut down event so that it can shutdown anytime(outside the schedule)

Comment: Guess this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101647/how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-when-shutting-down-windows

Comment: that definitely helps!